# AWS Step Functions : How to "rename" an input parameter using a Pass step

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine which contains the following relevant states:

```yaml
States:
  'Analyze Report':
    Type: Task
    Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke'
    Parameters:
      FunctionName: '(redacted)'
    OutputPath: '$.Payload'
    Next: 'Setup Email'
  'Setup Email':
    Type: Pass
    Result:
      recipients: '$.accounts'
      subject: 'some email subject'
      body: 'some email body'
    ResultPath: '$'
    Next: 'Send Email'
  'Send Email':
    Type: Task
    Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke'
    Parameters:
      FunctionName: '(redacted)'
    OutputPath: '$.Payload'
    Next: '(some downstream task)'
```

The output of the lambda function associated with the `Analyze Report` step is of the form:

```json
{
  "accounts": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
  "error_message": null,
  "success": true
}
```

The lambda function associated with the `Send Email` step expects an input of the form:

```json
{
  "recipients": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
  "subject": "some email subject",
  "body": "some email body"
}
```

When looking at a test execution of the state function, it seems like the `Setup Email` step is not successfully interpolating the `$.accounts` string into the `accounts` array output from the `Analyze Report` step. Instead, the `Send Email` step sees the following input:

```json
{
  "recipients": "$.accounts",
  "subject": "some email subject",
  "body": "some email body"
}
```

I have tried various combinations of things like setting:

```yaml
# (within the `Setup Email` step)
Result:
  'recipients.$': '$.accounts'
```

But it doesn't want to seem to interpolate. The documentation provided by AWS seems a bit lacking in this manner.

**TL;DR:**  How do you effectively "rename" an input parameter (with an array value) using a step function step of type `Pass`?

Comment: A potentially relevant [discussion thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=754973)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Parameters` in your `Pass` state. Here is an example:

```json
{
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states",
  "StartAt": "Hello",
  "States": {
    "Hello": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "newName.$": "$.oldName"
      },
      "Next": "World"
    },
    "World": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "World",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the above with a payload of `{ "oldName": "some value" }` the input to the second state is `{ "newName": "some value" }`.

Comment: Thank you! I just stumbled upon this myself and was about to answer, so I can verify that this works!

Comment: I had a similar problem, but even after adding `{"newName.$" : "$.oldName"}` to the `Parameters` of my `Pass` state, I got an error saying `The JSONPath '$.oldName' specified for the field 'newName.$' could not be found in the input '"{\"oldName\": \"some value\"}"'`. In my case, this was because I had done a `return json.dumps(payload)` in the Python code of my first Lambda. I needed to do `return payload` instead.